# How to insert records more than 15000 at one go in custom list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

In one of my projects my requirement is to insert/add more than 15000 records/entries at one og in a custom list.

After searching some of the blogs i found some useful information about adding bulk entries in custom list.I tried to add by the batch files, i called processbatchdata method for bulk entries.

Referred link : http://www.arboundy.com/code/sharepoint/bulk-add-new-items-to-a-sharepoint-list-using-processbatchdata/

However i ended up with the performance issue,its taking more than 2 minutes for adding 5000 entries.

Can anyone help me on this issue.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Seems like that's the best approach.. minimal time.. [SharePoint: Using Batch-Updates to speed up performance?](http://apmblog.compuware.com/2009/01/20/sharepoint-using-batch-updates-to-speed-up-performance/)

Answer (score 3):

If you are complaining about 2 minutes being slow for 5k items, presumably this isn't a one time import - you may consider looking at [Business Connectivity Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798319.aspx) to connect directly to your external data source.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a frequent step or just a one time task?

If it's frequent, I recommend NOT doing this in SharePoint! Sorry, I don't have a good answer. I would revisit the requirements and look at farming this high amount of data into another SQL database and use BCS to connect and manage the data.

I strongly oppose high amounts of data in SP, especially if this is a frequent task... Check out BCS